# Text output with colors in xed text editor

Tags: text, editors

I'm executing a nodejs project with roarr library for log messages; when I write the output to a file and open the geretated text file with `xed`, I have the following codes indicate, I argue, the colors to format the text; for example:

```
[32mqueue: [39mDOWNLOAD_QUEUE
```

means:

[image]

"queue" in green and "DOWNLOAD_QUEUE" in gray color (this is the output in the console).

How can I set text colors in Linux `xed`?